# opencart, shop by motor bike selector in top menu

Tags: opencart, product, categories

I wish to find a solution on implementing a menu item (probably final step) which in:

step 1 (homescreen): displays "by brand"

step 2 : displays all brands (not nec. alphabetically)

step 3 : brand model and beneath all the model parts (already inserted) that fit on that model.

Is such an implementation possible in opencart?

PS: this is my first attempt with opencart, I reached to attributes where I thought I was close but I failed to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to **StackOverflow**!

In opencart (administration) You can manage brands (manufacturers) and then add products to that manufacturers (interjoin appropriate products with their manufacturers).

Then just check all the footer related files (controller, language file, template) and copy the `manufacturer` things to the header related files while positioning the link to manufacturers within main navigation and translating *Manufacturers* to *By Brands*.

And You are done!